# Unable to define predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have just started learning `Prolog` and so pardon me if this is a bit naive, or rather a lot naive. I am trying to define this predicate

```
| ?- times(M,N,Product) :- Product is M*N.
```

which gives me this error

```
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,(:-)/2),top_level/0)
```

I am using GNU Prolog. What is the fault here ?

Comment: This is odd.  I tried it with GNU Prolog (via IDEOne) and got no errors).

Comment: Enter `[user].` before the rule.

Comment: @false: Could you please be a bit more elaborate ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As false said, If you want to define a predicate or function during the execution of the interpreter, you must enter the "user" mode of the interpreter, by typing:

```
['user'].
```

After typing your predicates, you'll just need to leave this "zone", as a confirmation to the interpreter that you're finished with the coding, and it can start to compile your predicates to bytecodes -- which you'll be, then, allowed to access through your function names.

To leave the "user" mode simply press `ctrl + d`.

Tested in both swipl and gprolog:

```
SWI-Prolog version 5.10.4
(GNU Prolog) 1.3.0
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Check user manual 8.7  Dynamic clause management especially: asserta/assertz.

Next will help you to define new predicate in gprolog:

asserta( ( times(M,N,Product) :- Product is M*N ) ).